# Filter rows in multidimensional array to remove duplicated values and rows with no unique values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering

I am trying to manipulate a multi-dimensional array to filter out repeated data.

Sample input:

```
$test = [
    [
        "supplier" => "TEST DEPO",
        "rolanID" => array(123, 234, 456),
        "itemCount" => 3
    ],
    [
        "supplier" => "ANOTHER DEPO",
        "rolanID" => array(123, 786, 345),
        "itemCount" => 3
    ],
    [
        "supplier" => "ROLAN",
        "rolanID" => array(123, 234),
        "itemCount" => 2
    ]
];
```

With this array, I want to output like the below array. As we can see, if all rolanID is equal to one of the supplier then I don't want to add that array into the final array. For, an example the supplier "ROLAN" array is removed completely in the final array as its all rolanID is in the supplier "TEST DEPO" but the supplier "ANOTHER DEPO" has some rolanID that is not in the supplier "TEST DEPO" so, it is included that in the final array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supplier] => TEST DEPO
            [rolanID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123
                    [1] => 234
                    [2] => 456
                )

            [itemCount] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supplier] => ANOTHER DEPO
            [rolanID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 786
                    [1] => 345
                )

            [itemCount] => 2
        )
)
```

This is how I tried, but it does not work in some cases. For example, it only checks the first element of array with others. So, there will be multiple arrays with same rolanID that does not exists in first element of array.

```
$finalArray[] = $test[0];
for ($i=1; $i<count($test); $i++) {
    $id = array_diff($test[$i]['rolanID'], $test[0]['rolanID']);

    if (!empty($id)) {
        array_push($finalArray, array(
            'supplier' => $test[$i]['supplier'],
            'rolanID' => $id,
            'itemCount' => count($id),
        ));
    } 
}
```

Comment: So earlier occurring ids may stay, but any later occurrence must be removed. Yes?

Comment: @mickmackusa I think it is if any row's roland IDs are a subset of any other row's roland IDs, then it should be removed.

Comment: Do you have any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through each row. For every roland ID, collect all the indexes of rows wherever it is present.
- Loop through each row again. For every roland ID, collect all the intersect indexes of rows wherever it is present using [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). If the size of the intersected indexes array is greater than `1`, it means it is a subset of some other row, else it isn't and we can include it in our result.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php


$set = [];

foreach($test as $idx => $row){
    foreach($row['rolanID'] as $id){
        $set[$id] = $set[$id] ?? [];
        $set[$id][] = $idx;
    }
}

$result = [];

foreach($test as $idx => $row){
    $intersects = [];
    foreach($row['rolanID'] as $key => $id){
        $intersects = $key === 0 ? $set[ $id] : array_intersect($intersects, $set[$id]);
    }
    
    if(count($intersects) === 1) $result[] = $row;
}


print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/9e7b7)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue so this is what I done.

```
$tempArray = array();
$results = array();
            
foreach ($test as $index => $supplier) {
       $supplier['rolanID'] = array_diff($supplier['rolanID'], $tempArray); // check if there is any new ids
       $results[] = $supplier;
                
       if (!empty($supplier['rolanID'])) { // check if there is any new ids
            $tempArray = array_merge($tempArray, $supplier['rolanID']);  // merge the existing ids with new ids              
       }                                                       
       else {
            unset($test[$index]);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a list of all unique rolanIDs while you iterate.

Filter each row's rolanIDs -- if any left over ids in the subarray, store the filtered/modified row in the output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QAFX1))

```
$allRolanIDs = [];
$result = [];
foreach ($test as $row) {
    $uniqueIds = array_diff($row['rolanID'], $allRolanIDs);
    if ($uniqueIds) {
        array_push($allRolanIDs, ...$uniqueIds);
        $result[] = array_replace($row, ['rolanID' => $uniqueIds]);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```